# Using filter_at on grouped data for multiple conditions in R

Tags: r, group-by, tidyverse, filtering

I have a dataset (df) like the following:

| ID | Var_1 | Var_2 | Var_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C21 | D06 | C7931 |
| 1 | A2934 | D06 | D210 |
| 1 | H2710 | J1029 | C71 |
| 2 | C7932 | J281 | C7931 |
| 2 | L971 | C7932 | C71 |
| 3 | F82419 | K2910 | G8201 |
| 3 | K291 | D06 | C71 |
| 3 | C21 | D06 | C71 |

I want to filter the dataset so that any ID groups with "C7931" or "C7932" in any column that starts with Var could remain. To note, in my actual dataset, I have hundreds of these columns with names that all start with Var_#.

In other words, the output dataset would only keep all the rows in ID 1 and 2.

This is what I have tried so far, but didn't seem to work:

```
x <- df %>% group_by(ID) %>% union(filter_at(any(df, vars(starts_with("Var"), any_vars(.=="C7931"))), filter_at(any(df, vars(starts_with("Var"), any_vars(.=="C7932))))
```

Comment: `...filter(if_any(starts_with("Var"), \(x) x %in% c("C7931", "C7932")))` should work. Requires `dplyr` version 1.04 or higher.

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the response! What does the \(x) x %in% do? I tried this code but it didn't seem to work :(

Comment: Starting in R version 4.1 (May 2021), `\(x)` is a shortcut for `function(x)`. If you're using an older version of R, you can use `function(x) x %in% c("C7931", "C7932")`